# Can I add FreeBSD as Target Platform to Delphi XE2 IDE?

Tags: delphi, cross-platform, delphi-xe2

My utility compiles fine with both FPC and Delphi. Now I'd like to make an IDE to run FPC from the GUI for me as Target Platform. I've noticed what some project templates in RAD Studio's repository can into cross-platform build and some can not. So presume it is not hardcoded within IDE but configurable instead. Also, I'm aware what XE2 uses FPC for ARM cross-compilation. Therefore goes the question: can I configure that and how?

---

UPD: As i figured out, presence of "Target Platform" node in the Project Manager directly reflects presence of more than 1 child nodes under  in `ProjectName.dproj`. Dunno if finding is useful or not.

Comment: FreeBSD (and Linux) are *not* supported under Delphi XE2.  Delphi (then under Borland) tried supporting Linux a few years ago, and it might(now under Embarcadero) try again someday.  And Lazarus/Free Pascal is very close to the commercial Delphi in many significant ways.  So *try* whatever you want - you might get lucky :)  But *no* guarantees ;)

Comment: @paulsm4, yep, since i'm not a MSBuild expert, trial-and-error is only way to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

No. XE2 supports `Win32/64`, `OSX` (using `FireMonkey`), and `iOS` (as you said, using `FPC`). It doesn't support any other targets. If you need to compile to another, you need to strictly use `FPC` and `Lazarus`; there's no way to add other targets to the IDE.

If you could add additional targets to the IDE, you'd think Embarcadero would have mentioned that as a pretty valuable piece of marketing information, and they didn't (not even in the new release of XE3).

Comment: How can you explain my observations?

Comment: Some of the templates are marked as supporting more than one of the platform that the IDE supports, not "supporting any platform you want".